# NULL evaluation failing when referencing a backing property from a SharePoint class

Tags: c#, collections

I'm retrieving information from SharePoint with the following code. In testing I'm intentionally sending my code to the catch block which should be making this method return null:

```
private static ListItemCollection LoadListItemCollection()
{
    try
    {
        using (var ctx = new ClientContext("http://sharepoint"))
        {
            var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Resource Orders");

            var query = new CamlQuery
            {
                ViewXml =
                    @"<Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name=""Status""></FieldRef><Value Type=""Text"">Approved</Value></Eq><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name=""Status"" /></FieldRef></IsNotNull></Or></Where>"
            };

            var collListItem = list.GetItems(query);

            ctx.Load(
                collListItem,
                items =>
                    items.Include(
                        item => item.Id,
                        item => item.DisplayName,
                        item => item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments,
                        item => item["Persona"],
                        item => item["Quantity_x0020_Ordered"],
                        item => item["Resource_x0020_Name"],
                        item => item["Title"],
                        item => item["Customer_x0020_E_x002d_mail"],
                        item => item["Customer_x0020_Phone_x0020_Numbe"],
                        item => item["Customer_x0020_Street"],
                        item => item["Customer_x0020_Suburb"],
                        item => item["Customer_x0020_Postcode"],
                        item => item["Organization"]));

            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            return collListItem;
        }
    }
    catch (System.Net.WebException)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Order processor was unable to reach the SharePoint server to download orders.",
                        "SharePoint Currently Unavailable", MessageBoxButton.OK);

        return null;
    }

}
```

When I'm implementing this further up the stack I'm referencing the following property (in the same class as the method above):

```
public static ListItemCollection LatestOrders => ordersCache = LoadListItemCollection();
```

This is used like so:

```
var collListItem = Orders.LatestOrders;
```

I was originally testing that orders were retrieved using the following:

```
if (!collListItem.Any())
{
    MessageBox.Show(
        "No resource orders are currently within the queue.",
        "Order Center",
        MessageBoxButton.OK,
        MessageBoxImage.Information);

    return;
}
```

But for some reason even when returning null with my above method it's failing this test and moving onto the next part of the code.

In order to overcome this I've then tried doing the following:

```
if (!collListItem.Any() || collListItem.Equals(null))
{
    MessageBox.Show(
        "No resource orders are currently within the queue.",
        "Order Center",
        MessageBoxButton.OK,
        MessageBoxImage.Information);

    return;
}
```

But this is failing in this section statement with the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred
>   in System.Core.dll

What am I misunderstanding when trying to work with my object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
if (!collListItem.Any() || collListItem.Equals(null))
   ...
```

use

```
if (collListItems == null || collListItem.Count == 0) // array? - Length
   ...
```

The problem is what `null` check should happens first, otherwise you get `NullReferenceException` when trying to call any member of not existing instance (same is true for extension method if you don't check for `null` there).

I don't know how to find sources of `Any` to see what is inside, but it probably doesn't allow `null` (and throw is expected behavior) and another thing it could have some *overhead*, while direct `Count` check is clear and effecient. You can keep `Any()` instead of `Count == 0` if you find it more clear, but `null` check is obligatory.

Comment: Isn't that the point of Any()? What's  the technical difference (so I can understand this)?